# GTM Click Element trigger isn't firing

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to fire a GTM trigger based on the settings below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBGLD.png

But when I test it, it says that not all conditions are met, see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XvM3.png

And this is what I see in GTM preview mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QX7v.png

I can't trigger on click class, since there are more buttons with them same name and I want to track this particular button.

What am I missing here? Hope someone is willing to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the HTML code (as it appears in the browser's `view source`) of the button that you want to track?

Comment: Hi Karthik, sure! Here it is: https://ibb.co/HYQ3cWV

Comment: I can't seem to access the URL. It gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Could you copy the one-line HTML of the tracked element and paste it in your question? Meanwhile, the screenshots show that it's the CSS selector filter that is failing, and the CSS selector refers to a couple of bootstrap classes on the element, which is not a reliable filter in itself. Also, I would expect the button to be a `<button>` element, whereas your filter suggests that you're putting it on a `<div>`.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6"> 
    <a class="green-btn " href="/webshop/klant-worden/register.jsp" data-title="Staan wij straks bij u voor de deur?">Klant worden</a> 
   </div>

Comment: I guess that makes sense. My explanation will probably too long for a comment. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` is a wrapper around the actual clickable item you're tracking, which is an `<a>` tag. It is very likely that every time the click occurs, it is the `<a>` element that becomes the `Click Element` (it is usually hard for a `div` wrapper to claim the click over a clickable child - such as a link or a button), which has the class `green-btn` and not `col-sm-6 col-md-6`.

Since you say that the `green-btn` class is applied to other buttons you **don't* want to track, I could suggest two alternatives:

1. If you have access to the development team that maintains the
   website in question, and if you could get them to add a unique `id`
   attribute to this `<a>`, I highly recommend doing that. You could
   then use the `id` attribute via a CSS selector or the `Click ID` GTM
   attribute to target the button.
2. If #1 is not possible, you could update your current CSS selector to
   be more specific, like so: `div.col-sm-6.col-md-6 > a.green-btn`.
   For this to work reliably, you have to make sure that the only
   element that matches this selector in the whole website is this
   button that you want to track.

Please try and let me know how it goes.

[Edit: Added a "don't" that was missing in my original answer. I usually leave my mistakes alone, but this one would change the meaning of a core point entirely for anyone who stumbles upon this answer in future.]

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I think I will go with solution #1 and ask the dev team to make some adjustments on order for me to get this done right.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the `Click Element` might not track as we expected

But that fine, here is some example

```html
<div class='abc'>
  <a>
</div> 


<div class='abc'>
  <span>
     <button></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you think we track `div.abc` is enough. But sometimes it just not as we expected.

My solutions is : I will track all the element inside the `div.abc`

{{Click Element}} > match CSS Selector > `div.abc, div.abc *`

This will trigger no matter which element inside the `div.abc` or itself being click.

Maybe you can give it shot.